# Systrace - error truncating /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/set_ftrace_filter: No such device (19) unable to start

Tags: ddms, android-kernel, systrace

I am currently working on a project which aims to find out what the system is doing behind a series of user interaction on the android UI. For example, if user click send button in Facebook Messenger, the measured response time for such action is 1.2 seconds. My goal is to figure out what the 1.2 seconds consist of. My friend suggested that I should take a look into 'Systrace'.

However, when I tried systrace on my HTC one M8, I have encountered some problems:
First, error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite - no such file or directory. I solved this problem by building up the support of the kernel following http://opensourceforu.com/2010/11/kernel-tracing-with-ftrace-part-1/ and mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug. Then I could find the tracing directory. Besides, I set ro.debuggable=1 in file default.prop within Ramdisk and burn the boot.img into my phone.

Now I encounter another problem: when I run - python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm, the following error(19) pop up: error truncating /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/set_ftrace_filter: No such device (19). I don't know if the way my building up kernel support for systrace is incorrect or anything is missing.

Could anyone helps me out with this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have worked out the solution. My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 + HTC one M8. I will write the steps as followed:

1. open terminal and enter: `$adb shell`
2. (1) `$su` (2) `$mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug`. Now you should be able to see many directories under /sys/kernel/debug/. (You may cd into /sys/kernel/debug to confirm this)
3. New a new terminal and enter: `dd if=/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/boot of=/sdcard/boot.img` to generate the boot.img kernel image from your device.
4. Use AndroidImageKitchen to unpack the boot.img and find the default.prop within Ramdisk folder. Then change `ro.debuggable=0` to `ro.debuggable=1`. Repack the boot.img and flash boot it to your device.
5. Once the device boot, under terminal, enter: adb root and message like: restarting adbd as root may pop up. Disconnect the USB and connect again.
6. cd to the systrace folder, e.g. ~/androidSDK/platform-tools/systrace and use:
   `python systrace.py --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html sched gfx view wm`
7. Now you may able to generate your own systrace files.